# How do I use the since and until parameters in twint?

Tags: python, format, match, twint

Im using the twint package to get all tweets in english since 2016-01-01 until 2021-01-01 for the search btc and save it as a csv file. My code looks as follow (im using a jupyter notebook)

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
import twint

#configuration
config = twint.Config()
config.Search = "btc"
config.Lang = "en"
config.Since = '2016–01–01'
config.Until = '2021-01-01'
config.Store_csv = True
config.Output = "BTCtweet.csv"
#running search
twint.run.Search(config)
```

When I run the script I get the following error:
ValueError: time data '2016–01–01 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

I have run the script without the Since and Until parameters and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Try to delete and retype your hyphens (-) between numbers (if you copied/pasted into Jupyter Notebook). It worked for me!